# JavaScript How to define an array of undefined length of empty objects?

Tags: javascript

```
var array = [];

var object = {};
```

Now, I need an array of empty objects.

```
array[0] = {};
array[1] = {};
//........
//........
```

and

```
var array = [{}];
```

is obviously not right.

How to define array of (empty) objects in JS?

```
var array = [{},{},{},{},.........];
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

The reason I need is the same reason that having an array with undefined length is useful, and mathematically natural in some cases.

I need object wrappers, and for initialization, it's just an empty object, like some values are null or undefined in many cases.

so, I'll have

var object = {};

`array[0].value = 'foo', array[1].value = 'bar'.....`

However, I do need multiple object wrappers, and the number is not pre-determined, so consequently, I need an arrays of the objects.

So, I am sorry, I modify my Question title

**JavaScript How to define an array of undefined length of empty objects?**

Comment: you just need to declare an empty array and push an object int o it like `array.push(object)`..

Comment: whats wrong with var array = [{}]; that will give you an array containing one empty object?

Comment: There is no problem writing `var array = [{}, {}, {}];` to make an array of objects.

Comment: why would you need that? I'm curious about the engineering protocole behind that

Comment: Sebas, good quesion, I edit my Q.

Comment: Does it *need* to be an array or would lyou be fine with an object with `get` and `set` methods?

Comment: missingno, well, to be exact, it's a property like. `array[0].value = 'foo',array[1].value = 'bar'.....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays can grow and shrink dynamically. So from a certain point of view, they are already of undefined length. You can always add new objects to it if you want to.

You can also create a helper function which checks first if an object exists at a certain position and if not, creates a new one.

You mentioned `array[2].value = 'foo'` as an example. Here is a helper function that you could use:

```
function getObjectAtIndex(arr, index) {
    return arr[index] || (arr[index] = {});
}
```

and then, instead of writing `array[2].value = 'foo'`, you'd write:

```
getObjectAtIndex(array, 2).value = 'foo'
```

Comment: Nice. I though that using the literal notation didn't affect the length property.

Comment: You mean `arr[index]`? It does, the length is always set to the highest index + 1.

Comment: That's what I meant. I thought that `length` was updated only when using Array methods :/

Comment: Thanks, Felix Kling. I think this is the only way to define(or supply by the helper function) an array of undefined length of empty objects. Your answer is checked.

Answer (score 3):

In your array, pushing object in any way is right. That's totally ok. like:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({}); // ok
aa[1] = {} // also ok
```

or:

```
var arr = [{}, {}, {}]; // the way you are doing is also fine
```

Or, if you want to do it via loop, that is also fine. Like:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    arr[i] = {};
}
```

Comment: Well, I agree especially, the last code would be chosen if I know nothing else to do, however, my question is that is it possible to do that for undefined length of array. On second thought, probably it's not possible.

Comment: length of an array can not be undefined. Either it would be 0 or a fixed length. You can get the length of the array anytime, right?

Comment: Thanks, please check out the answer I've approved. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the way to write

```
var array = [];
array[0] = {};
array[1] = {};
//........
//........
```

in a sane manner without lots of copy paste is to use a for loop:

```
var array = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  array[i] = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that an array like `var array = [];` **is** an array of Objects.  Based on how Javascript works, you never have to worry about null-pointer exceptions, so just define the array and act like you initialized it with the empty objects and see if it works

Comment: Thanks, but for instance, if I do `var array = []; `, I can not add an property like `array[2].value = 'foo'`

Comment: why would you want to use ".value" ?
Just do array[2]='foo'
Note you could also do array.hey='foo'
http://jsfiddle.net/Kkf6t/1/

Comment: Because, as I mentioned, the object wrapper is the purpose to implement. Pleaser refer my Q.